# Bootstrap Horizontal Form and Column Changes

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm working with a [Bootstrap Horizontal Form](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#horizontal-form) for the first time and have taken their example and am trying to convert this into 4 columns. Columns 1 and 3 will have the field labels and columns 2 and 4 will have the field inputs.

I would like to have the rows in columns 1 and 2 independent of the rows in columns 3 and 4, so that if a radio button set was in row 4 it wouldn't change the height of a text input that was in row 2. Here's my working sample:

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Email</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
    
    <fieldset class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
      <legend class="col-form-label col-sm-2 pt-0">Radios</legend>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="form-check">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="gridRadios" id="gridRadios1" value="option1" checked>
          <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios1">
            First radio
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="gridRadios" id="gridRadios2" value="option2">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios2">
            Second radio
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check disabled">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="gridRadios" id="gridRadios3" value="option3" disabled>
          <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios3">
            Third disabled radio
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
    
    
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Password</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
  </div>
  
  
  
  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-sm-2">Checkbox</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="gridCheck1">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="gridCheck1">
          Example checkbox
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign in</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

As you can see it looks terrible at the moment - I can't work out how to have effectively 2 columns on horizontal tables and fields that are independent of each other. At the moment the radio buttons are impacting the size of the gap between the email and password fields in the first column of field inputs - I would like to make these independent of each other if that is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Add Class `col` on

```
<fieldset class="form-group col">
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Email</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
    
    <fieldset class="form-group col">
    <div class="row">
      <legend class="col-form-label col-sm-2 pt-0">Radios</legend>
      <div class="col-sm-8"> <!-- change Here -->
        <div class="form-check">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="gridRadios" id="gridRadios1" value="option1" checked>
          <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios1">
            First radio
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="gridRadios" id="gridRadios2" value="option2">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios2">
            Second radio
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check disabled">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="gridRadios" id="gridRadios3" value="option3" disabled>
          <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios3">
            Third disabled radio
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
    
    
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Password</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
  </div>
  
  
  
  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-sm-2">Checkbox</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="gridCheck1">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="gridCheck1">
          Example checkbox
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign in</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: This is close, but the height of the radio set is affecting the gap between the email and the password fields in the first column. Ideally I'd like these to be separate so that I have rows in the first column and rows in the 2nd column and the height of these rows is not affected by content in the other column. Is this possible?